# find subword of given query from table?

Tags: mysql

```
-------------------------------
name            | address
-------------------------------
raj kumar       | park street        
yogin patel     | ghari chowk     
raju singh      | sultan ganj
```

I searched for park road in table and I could not find it(that's ok).But what query will I use such that I search for parkroad (no space between the words) and at least I receive a details of row containing either park or road or both?

Please give some general Query so that it can be applied for all words whichever I want to search?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please give us the query you have tried till now?

Comment: I dont know which query to use , for this reason I am asking here.If you have any idea plz suggest

Comment: you should explore LIKE operators

Comment: I couldn't find any and if you know then plz help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
SELECT name, address FROM table_name 
WHERE address LIKE '%park%' or address LIKE '%road%';
```

You should try this out more to identify what you're exactly looking for.

Comment: thats fine but can you give the query how you seperated single word(parkroad) into two words (park,road) –

Comment: @user3717804 Well to do that you're going to need to split that yourself by using the .split() method. If you're sending an address with multiple words then you may want to split each word and then generate a dynamic query where you append those words

Comment: @user3717804 I think I got what you're saying with the no spaces just now so for that I think you will need to loop the word in itself and then append to the like operator, i.e. address LIKE '%p%' OR address LIKE '%pa%' or address LIKE '%par%'...something like that. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other way. You might want to wait for someone who could answer that for you here though

Comment: @user3717804 also to separate words like parkroad into two or more i think you'll need to know what those words are or have words like road, street as keywords and then identify them and then split them accordingly. I don't think there's another way around it

Comment: can it be like first count the no. of alphabet, say the word is rajsingh,so no.of alphabet is 8. now divide it into half you will get two word (rajs,ingh) by using like rajs% or %ingh. this can be one of the answer. what do you say

Comment: @user3717804 but that would only work in case of some words. i.e. if you were to search for parkroad then you maybe able to do that, but if it were something else like newcastleroad then you wouldn't be able to identify it properly. you'd split the word into newcas and tleroad...you wouldn't be able to search for words containing 'road'

Comment: can i say that my explaination will work for only two words having no space in between and not three or more words